# GNOME: Automatic window placement according to a set of rules

Tags: x11, gnome, desktop

KDE Plasma has an extremely useful set of features ("KWin Rules") that can automatically apply a number of characteristics (position, size, workspace, etc.) to windows according to a flexible set of rules (window title, WM_CLASS, etc.).

Is there anything like this for GNOME (as an extension) or something that is desktop-agnostic and works for X11? It is surely something that is extremely valuable for workflow optimization and so far I've found nothing of the kind.

The most common scenario is wanting to place new windows of a certain application (for example, Nautilus) always in the same position and size.